# DataTable in Bokeh layout forcing blank space in row

Tags: python, bokeh

I am using Bokeh `gridplot` to layout a figure, widgets, and a DataTable.
After upgrading to Bokeh 1.3.4, my layout changed, with space inserted between
the figure and the checkbox groups. See screenshot below:

[image]

It seems that the `width=1000` of the `DataTable` is forcing the white space. If I remove the `DataTable`, the layout appears properly, with the checkbox groups located directly adjacent to the radial plot figure.

Here is my relevant code for the layout:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# LAYOUT
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
hor_layout_date_slider = (
    row(
      column(blank_wb),
      column(date_slider_wb),
    )
)

hor_layout_time_cb = (
    row(
      column(div_time),
      column(rg_time),
    )
)

vert_layout_1 = (
    column(
      row(div_zone),
      row(cb_zone),
      row(div_trigger),
      row(cb_trigger),
    )
)

vert_layout_2 = (
    column(
      row(div_location),
      row(cb_location),
      row(div_type),
      row(cb_type),
    )
)

grid = gridplot(
  children = [
    [hor_layout_date_slider],
    [hor_layout_time_cb],
    [scatter_fig, vert_layout_1, vert_layout_2],
    [data_table]
    ],
    toolbar_options=dict(logo=None),
    sizing_mode='fixed',
)

curdoc().add_root(grid)
```

Each element is defined with it's own height and width, everything is `sizing_mode='fixed'`. The radial plot has `width=600, height=600` and the checkbox groups are each `width=200, height=105` with `Div` elements for the titles that are each `width=200, height=15`.

**How do I modify my layout to get the checkbox groups to be located directly adjacent to the figure (and above the table)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a resolution to my own question.

If I use `layout` instead of `gridplot`, everything works.

Commented code shows original implementation, and new code shows revised implementation using `layout`:

```
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot, layout

#grid = gridplot(
  #children = [
    #[hor_layout_date_slider],
    #[hor_layout_time_cb],
    #[scatter_fig, vert_layout_1, vert_layout_2],
    #[data_table]
    #],
    #toolbar_options=dict(logo=None),
    #sizing_mode='fixed',
#)

grid = layout(
  children=[
    [hor_layout_date_slider],
    [hor_layout_time_cb],
    [scatter_fig, vert_layout_1, vert_layout_2],
    [data_table]
    ],
    sizing_mode='fixed',
)
```

Note that I also had to drop `toolbar_options` as this is not a valid attribute when using `layout`.